# What flexible but stable outdoor material can be used to fill a gap under a metal frame suspended window?

Tags: landscaping, outdoor

To describe the situation a bit more:

I have an *outdoor* window with a metal frame. There is about a 10-15cm gap along the bottom of it. Tiled floor. The gap is not even height, so it's literally about 10-11cm on one side and it widens to about 15-16 cm towards the other side. The floor is tiled.

I need to fill this gap with something that will prevent water/dust from flowing from one side to the other (not to worry: each side has a drain) and I was thinking to use some kind of rubber and cut it to size. But given its somewhat un-even height, I thought there might be a better material. Something easy to work with. Maybe something originally soft and it hardens when exposed to air and maintains waterproof quality long term?

Answer (score 1):

Brick (or structural tile) and mortar. Use more mortar on the low side to even things up. If you want "flexible" use the brick and mortar to make a smaller, even gap you can caulk.

Answer (score 0):

What about epifoam packaging?  I reuse it when I find it used for larger items like furniture, tv or computers
It can be cut to shape, stable outdoors and any gaps can be sealed with latex caulking